# ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: networking, server, mount, ssh

I cannot ssh anymore after rebooting my ubuntu 14.04 VPS. Here are the results:

```
#ssh -vvv user@0.0.0.0    

OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 0.0.0.0 [0.0.0.0] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused
```

and

```
# nmap -Pn 0.0.0.0    
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-30 23:16 UTC
Nmap scan report for (0.0.0.0)
Host is up (0.00067s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp  filtered smtp
465/tcp filtered smtps
587/tcp filtered submission
```

I can now only access the VPS after mounting it with another VPS. I assume that opening port 22 might solve the problem, but could not find a way to do that after mounting it with another VPS and editing file. Can anyone please help, how I can do it!

Comment: what's the output for "service ssh status", you should make sure sshd is started.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to 0.0.0.0? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: I just replaced my ip with 0.0.0.0 before posting here. -@dobey

Comment: @alfred they can't run that, since the only access they have to the original virtual machine is mounting the disk image for that virtual machine in another virtual machine.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think you can chroot to the mounted disk, check log file to see if the ssh service is up, and do fixing accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by 'mounting a vps'. However port 22 will definitely be needed for SSH by default.
If you have Uncomplicated Firewall installed and enabled then you can run:

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

If not then you can use iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Or you can change the port that SSH uses by modifying it's config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
Edit the file using your favourite text editor, I like to use nano because other editors scare me:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Now, assuming that by VPS you mean Virtual Private Server, perhaps by

> I can now only access the VPS after mounting it with another VPS.

you are saying you are trying to create a virtual machine on your PC using something like VirtualBox? If this is the case then you would need to allow port 22 on the guest machine, the host, and possibly your router (if you are trying to ssh in from somewhere outside of your network). I hope this helps you friend.

-- edit --
What you need to do then is this:

Create a file with the ideal set of iptables rules in it.

Have that file loaded at boot.

I won't lie, I'm not confident enough in my knowledge of IP tables to help you with this so I won't try and risk misleading you, sorry.

Comment: It is a Virtual Private Server. I'm not being able to run any command in terminal because to access it, I have to turn it off and only can modify files. Changing port is not working! Can you please suggest any other way!